# Transition strip for tiled trap door

Tags: flooring

I need some advice on attaching a stainless steel t-joint transition strip to my trap door which is in my laundry room.  I want to use a strip that is wide enough to cover the cut in my tile.  I want a 45-degree cut at the corners, so the strip must be at least an inch wide.  Please help!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: With regard to steel versus tile, you should add a rubber gasket or barrier of some kind so that there is some cusion between the flange and tile.

Comment: More specifically, you should add the gasket to the edge of the tile. I believe it would be better to adhere the gasket to the floor (like, in case the flange gets bent; the whole point is to protect the tile).

Answer (score 1):

Stainless steel will not be a user friendly material to cut. I would suggest using an aluminum angle instead. It is readily available, one leg will be on the floor level to cover the tile edge, the other will go into the opening to allow it to be secured to the framing under the tile floor.
[image: tile trim]

Comment: Good suggestion, but aluminum is far less strong. If a t-molding is ever lowered onto an obstruction, it'll be ruined. Stainless could be cut with a hack saw and shaped with a grinder or rotary tool.

Comment: I used aluminum around a floor access, it worked out really well. It had a floating floor, so I took 1 1/2"X1 1/2"X1/16" aluminum angle and ripped one leg to 1" wide. That left the other 1 1/2" leg to be drilled and countersunk. The top part set to the floor snug and the screws certainly held it in place. Yes SS will be more durable, but to do to the SS what I did to the aluminum would need to be done in a metal shop. A costly proposition. This picture I have added is for the same thing I speak of as the OP asked, a trap door in a laundry room floor.

Comment: The OP wants to use T-molding, though, presumably so that there's no gap. This means that there's a floating flange subject to damage.

Comment: I understand that, it also has to be a matter of what is available. Perhaps there is but I have not found any on any hardware store shelf. T molding is the best bet for a seal. The double angle will work too. After all, how often will access be needed? it can be sealed very well as part of the supporting structure.